# Company wants references AFTER I signed job offer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, references

I received a formal offer from a company and signed the offer letter and background check information. They also asked for references and I'm afraid I might lose the offer as I have no references. Don't companies ask for references BEFORE an offer?

Comment: In this case, clearly not. What's your actual question here?

Comment: Assuming this is your first job do you not have school teachers you can use  or if you had a part time Job can your employer not give you a reference?

Comment: You are not actually employed by them until you start your first day.  They can make you jump through what ever hoops they want, it will be up to you how you handle that.

Comment: Not uncommon at all. It may be their policy, based on guidance from their hr/legal, to not ask for references until after you've signed the consent to background check. Becuase engaging the people who are your references really is considered part of the background process, and doing that without signed consent could be problematic.

Answer (score 5):

It's very common, in my experience. The purpose is to do a background check of some sort, even if that check is simply checking references. It saves them effort before the offer and gets the whole HR process rolling. Asking beforehand can just lead to wasted effort if they decide not to make an offer at all.

Since you've just signed the offer, I can guarantee you that it's pending verification of your information, even if not explicitly stated. If they find out you've been deceptive, they'll withdraw the offer.

No job offer, even in writing, is a guarantee. Companies have been known to rescind the offer if they find out more information later.

Answer (score 0):

My last contract had a clause that my employment is dependant on good references, and that these can be contacted at any time. So basically if they are negative they can revoke my employment.
It could be argued that this is not right, but in any case they can send you away with proper notice.
However a list of references is normally requested before the contract, but can be after the offer.
In this case they never asked.